# How to send personalized eMails to members of a contact-list in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email, contacts, personalization

I'd like to send a personalized eMail to all members of a given contact-list in Thunderbird.

For example I'd like to write

```
Dear [[[Title]]] [[[LastName]]],
```

Which is then (depneding on the current contact) converted into:

```
Dear Prof. Hugenhauer,
Dear Mr. Smith,
...
```

Is there a way (e.g. a plugin) that allows personalized mails?

Answer (score 2):

[Mail merge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/) is what you need.

> About this Add-on
>
> Mail Merge: If you want to send a mail to multiple recipients, there are three common problems: First you can't personalize the mail. Second you can't send a mail to more than 25, 100, ... recipients at once. Third the recipients should not see the other recipients.
>
> Mail Merge solves these problems by creating one single mail for each recipient from a draft!

You can take the data from a `.csv` file or address book.